# SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am writing a simple test using `react-native-testing-library` (my first steps with that library) in my react native expo app. But I am getting a confused error coming from somewhere inside `react-native` code base itself. Either there is something wrong with my code or there is a bug with `react-native-testing-library` npm library.

Here is simple jest test:

```
describe("AppTitle", () => {
  it("should display applicaton title", () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<AppTitle />);
    expect(getByText('App Name')).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

And here is the simple `<AppTitle />` component (just a View and a Text)

```
export const AppTitle = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>App Name</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
```

But I am getting this error when I run the test:

[image]

```
...../Utilities/warnOnce.js:15

const warnedKeys: {[string]: boolean} = {};
      ^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration

at ScriptTransformer.transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:471:17)
at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:513:25)
at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js:14:18)
...
```

This is a simple and straight forward template. Any help from a react-native + react-native-testing-library would be appreciate.

1. react: 16.8.3
2. react-native: fork from `Expo 33`
3. jest-expo: "^33.0.2"
4. react-native-testing-library": "1.7.0"

Comment: how did you set up TypeScript compiling? seems like your TS type declaration goes untransformed so JS interpreter suppose `:` to be just a label or something like that

Comment: @skyboyer I created this project with "expo init app_name". I have not ejected and I have messed up any setting. The new expo cli tool builds the app with babel7 which has built-in support for typescript. Maybe I should some preset in the babel.config.js...I don't know...

Comment: you need to install/setup `ts-jest` or `babel-jest` or check if it's configured if already installed https://levelup.gitconnected.com/creating-a-minimal-expo-react-native-project-with-typescript-and-jest-5979ab8d7c15 beware that TS support for Jest and for building are independent so even if one works another still may be misconfigured

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I installed ts-jest and configured jest.config. But now I get this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < (on the line for render(<AppTitle />). It looks like the .tsx file has not been transpiled. I continue to investigate

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I resolved this added  "preset": "react-native" in jest.config.js file

Comment: Sadly this didn't help me. I am still stuck at the same error as above :(

Comment: As per the Jest [documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-react-native.html), this is now supposed to be included by default in the package.json file

Answer (score 2):

I am using  expo in my project. I have same issue. i forgot to add "preset": "jest-expo" to package.json. i added then the problem solved.

```
 "jest": { "preset": "jest-expo" },
```