# Missing initializer in const declaration in jest and enzyme

Tags: jestjs, react-native, enzyme

I tried to test a react-native component but I got this error.

I realize that the error comes from `import  Convertor, { ConvertorComponent }   from '../components/Convertor.js` declared in the `convertor.test.js` file. I exported the component with `export ConvertorComponent` and with `export default Convertor`.

```
const warnedKeys: {[string]: boolean} = {};

SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration

at ScriptTransformer.transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:471:17)
at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:513:25)
at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js:14:18)
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158884/syntaxerror-missing-initializer-in-const-declaration

Comment: in short: there is some error in configuration so Typescript code is not transpiled into plain Javascript

Comment: I added  "preset": "react-native" in jest.config.js file and works! Thanks!