# Index.js:Missing Initializer in const declaration

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jsx

I've been trying react-native development and i am in its first stage so I was trying to create a simple Hello World Application but the system keeps showing an error I cannot solve.

[This is the result it shows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoWFt.png)

My index.js file is as below:

```
   import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

and the main App.js file is as below

```
export default class App extends React.Component{
  render()
  return {(
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.welcome}>
     Hello World!
   </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
};
```

i've fixed the babel and jest issues as well, any help is appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158884/syntaxerror-missing-initializer-in-const-declaration)

Answer (score 1):

In the render method the first curly bracket is in the wrong position, it should be after `render()` not after `return`:

```js
export default class App extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>
          Hello World!
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: That doesnot seem to be the issue,I checked the tutorial and rewrote the code as you told,the error still exists.