# Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to learning Javascript and making a sample project to test password strength based on the input that a user provides.

But along the way, I see an error message showing up as follows:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration

I researched on a similar link to this exact query here:
[SyntaxError: Missing initializer in const declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158884/syntaxerror-missing-initializer-in-const-declaration)

but it's related to *react* and I don't understand much.

Here, is my Javascript code with the function in particular that throws error:

```
function updateStrengthMeter() {
  const weaknesses = calculatePasswordStrength(passwordInput.value);
  let strength = 100;
  reasonsContainer.innerHTML = "";
  weaknesses.forEach((weakness) => {
    if (weakness == null) return;
    strength -= weakness.deduction;

    const messageElement.innerText = weakness.message;
    reasonsContainer.appendChild(messageElement);
  });
  strengthMeter.style.setProperty("--strength", strength);
}
```

What I discovered is that the error is related to const declaration at this line here:

```
const messageElement.innerText = weakness.message;
```

On internet research, I found this happens if you declare a const with no assignment. But, I wonder why it occurs for me because I have assigned value to it.

Now, I may be asking this question again but this time it's with a perspective of why the error occurs in a vanilla Javascript codebase.

```js
const strengthMeter = document.getElementById("strength-meter");
const passwordInput = document.getElementById("password-input");
const reasonsContainer = document.getElementById("reasons");

passwordInput.addEventListener("input", updateStrengthMeter);
updateStrengthMeter();

function updateStrengthMeter() {
    const weaknesses = calculatePasswordStrength(passwordInput.value);
    let strength = 100;
    reasonsContainer.innerHTML = "";
    weaknesses.forEach((weakness) => {
        if (weakness == null) return;
        strength -= weakness.deduction;

        const messageElement.innerText = weakness.message;
        reasonsContainer.appendChild(messageElement);
    });
    strengthMeter.style.setProperty("--strength", strength);
}

function calculatePasswordStrength(password) {
    const weaknesses = [];
    weaknesses.push(lengthWeakness(password));
    return weaknesses;
}

function lengthWeakness(password) {
    const length = password.length;

    if (length <= 5) {
        return {
            message: "Your password is too short",
            deduction: 40,
        };
    }

    if (length <= 10) {
        return {
            message: "Your password could be longer",
            deduction: 15,
        };
    }
}
```

```css
*::before,
*::after,
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color: hsl(261, 88%, 17%);
    color: hsl(261, 88%, 90%);
    text-align: center;
}

.strength-meter {
    position: relative;
    height: 2rem;
    width: 90%;
    border: 3px solid hsl(261, 88%, 57%);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.strength-meter::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(1% * var(--strength, 0));
    background-color: hsl(261, 88%, 67%);
    transition: width 200ms;
}

.password-input {
    margin-top: 1rem;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
    background-color: hsl(261, 88%, 25%);
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid hsl(261, 88%, 57%);
    outline: none;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0.3rem;
}

.password-input:focus {
    border-color: hsl(261, 88%, 70%);
}

.reasons > * {
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    color: hsl(261, 88%, 80%);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Password Strength</title>
        <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h1>Password Strength Test</h1>
        <div class="strength-meter" id="strength-meter"></div>
        <input class="password-input" id="password-input" value="password" type="text" autofocus aria-labelledby="password" />
        <div id="reasons" class="reasons"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `const messageElement.innerText = weakness.message;` is not even valid code - you cannot have a variable name with a dot in it. I doubt you're trying to even declare a variable there, it seems you should only have `messageElement.innerText = weakness.message` instead of a variable declaration

Comment: Okay so basically I was thinking of creating a `div` and assigning the text contents of `weakness.message`

Comment: You don't need the `const` keyword to make an assignment. You only need it if you want to create a new variable.

Comment: Creating a new div and assigning text contents?? Can yo paste your HTML here and perhaps your JS code to see what exactly you're looking for

Comment: @excetra Sure let me do that.

Comment: I think you want to create a new tag and assign it to the const. In that case you should check the usage of createElement here  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: yeah, that's similar to what I want. Can you illustrate how that would fix my logic here if I use that with const. i am sorry I am new to all this and would appreciate some hand on this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign a variable name with dot in it as rightly pointed out by @VLAZ
That is **not** allowed.
Now over to fixing your issue, you need to use [document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

**How?**

As per your code in the function `updateStrengthMeter()` add this before the incorrect const decalaration

```
const messageElement = document.createElement("div");
```

The above line creates a div tag(Feel free to use any other as per your need. i am just giving an example here)

*Side note:*
If you need to add attributes do that after , like this :

```
let expandingList = document.createElement('ul', { is : 'expanding-list' })
```

Check the linked MDN reference for more details.

**and now you can use the line as per your original code without the const keyword ofcourse**

```
messageElement.innerText = weakness.message;
```